# Core Bluetooth: Cannot find a BLE device in the app again if reinstalling the app without disconnecting the BLE device properly in the app

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode, core-bluetooth

When I reinstall the app without disconnecting the BLE device, the phone keeps the connection so when I reinstall my app and scan for a BLE device, the last connection will appear in os level, but not in-app level. This causes me to not discover a BLE device if it is not disconnected on the app properly before. My tester insists that if I reinstall the app, I should not see a connection and discover the BLE device anyways.

I can retrieve a BLE device connection in the app if I know the UUID and services, but it is impossible without these as I see in the documentation. Is there any other way to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is precisely what `retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices:)` is for. That will return already connected (at the OS level) peripherals that advertise a particular list of services.

You will still need to call `connect` on the returned peripherals. "Connect" in this context means "to the app," not "to the device." The docs refer to these "app" connections as "local."

Comment: the problem is that how am I suppose to get the services to call this method? In a fresh app, I won't have the services stored in the app. this call does not work if you don't provide the services.

Comment: You provide the service UUIDs, not CBServices. You need to know the service UUIDs of course. This is typical of almost all Core Bluetooth use cases. The only exception would be a general-purpose Bluetooth scanner, which correctly would not discover a device that is not advertising.

Comment: then there is no way to retrieve if I don't know the UUID.

Comment: No, but what problem are you trying to solve? Fetching all connected devices (even ones you have no knowledge of) would leak personally traceable information, and I'm not certain what you would do with it. I recommend opening a Feedback to Apple explaining what user problem you're solving and ask for an enhancement. (And I'd also love to know more about the problem you're solving.)

Comment: To be clear: you don't need to know the UUID of the *device*. You only need to know the UUID of at least one service you're interested in. If you're not going to communicate with a known service, what would you do with this information (outside of a general-purpose BLE scanner like nRF Connect, which sees things that advertise)? Also note that generally the connection will drop within some fairly short period of time if no app is using it. So the discovery problem will work itself out relatively quickly for BLE scanners.